# how to access 1-st payload which was before from(mypromise)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, rxjs

Could someone help(have lack of knowlage of rxjs)
I need to call 1 API after another with passing partly same params and don't know how to do it. in code should be clear. many many thanks in advance

```
const MyEpic = (action$) =>
action$.pipe(
    ofType(constants.QWERTY_REQUEST),
    switchMap((action) =>
        from(
            myApi1.checkCredentials(action.payload.userName, action.payload.password)
        ).pipe(
            map((action) => {
                return ({type: constants.QWERTY_SUCCESS, payload: action.payload.userName})}), //at this point there is no action.payload.userName how to get initial payload???
            catchError(() => {
                return of(...);
            })
        )
    )
```

Comment: Don't call the parameter 'action' if you don't want to shade the one from parent scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`action` parameter is shadowed. If the parameter with same name from parent scope needs to be accessed, names should differ:

```
   map((whatever) => {
        return ({type: constants.QWERTY_SUCCESS, payload: action.payload.userName})}),
        ...
```